How to convert a list or a table of latex equations into word format
I try to convert automatically a large table of latex equations into a word table. How to do that automatically, without having to select cells, one one by one and click on convert to professional equation?



ex1
ex2




\left(1 - a\right)^{2}
a \left(1 - a\right)


a \left(1 - a\right)
\left(1 - a\right)^{2}


a \left(1 - a\right)
a^{2}


a^{2}
a \left(1 - a\right)




Try Latex2rtf.
